# Object literal definition Javascript

Tags: javascript, object-literal

This is probably pedantic, but I'm working with a large project where performance matters.
Is there any performance difference between defining a large Object literal with many properties like so:

```
var obj={
  a:23,
  b: 'The square root of pie',
  c: ['2']
};
```

as opposed to:

```
var obj={};
obj.a=23;
obj.b='The square root of pie';
obj.c=['2'];
```

Is there any performance difference at all between the two?  Primarily I'm concerned for performance, but I am also interested in any other differences that may not affect performance at all.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: In what environment?  Not all browsers are created equal.  Or is this node, in which case it's going to be different yet again

Comment: @Tibrogargan - It's in the browser, but could be any number of different browsers

Comment: @Phil.  I could - and I'd probably catch any big performance hit, but if there are nuances that people no of, I might not catch or understand them all.  If no one has any insight, I will.

Comment: http://jsben.ch/c6S96

Comment: @phil - thanks.  I couldn't seem to phrase it right to find it.

Comment: @user1167442 no problems. If you're ever interested in running JS performance tests, look no further than https://jsperf.com/

Comment: @Tareq - That's a surprisingly large difference for such a small object.  I'm not convinced it will be huge with a large object..but thanks for the test and for the sight.

Comment: @phil - jsperf hasn't worked properly for me for a long time, and it usually doesn't even show me past tests when I go there from google.  Tareq just posted a link to a sight that I didn't know about.  Looks interesting.

Comment: @user1167442 That's exactly my point.  Browsers have different performance profiles

Comment: Oh wow, yeah. JSPerf seems pretty broken